# Highcharts :the code works in Fiddle but not i Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, charts, highcharts

I am very new to VS and Highcharts. So I need your help!

I get the error below when I run my code in VS:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts' Hse:95
```

(anonymous function)

It is working fine in Fiddle!
Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/ext/sparkline.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/ext/highcharts.js")"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div>
        <span class="inlinesparkline"></span>
        <span class="dynamicbar" ></span>
        <span class="container"></span> 
    </div>


    </div>
</div>


<div class="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //Highcharts
            $('.container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline'

                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Snow depth in the Vikjafjellet mountain, Norway'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'An example of irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                        month: '%e. %b',
                        year: '%b'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Snow depth (m)'
                    },
                    min: 0
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) + ': ' + this.y + ' m';
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
                    data: [
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 27), 0],
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6],
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7],
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 2), 0.8],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 8), 0.78],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 12), 0.98],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 27), 1.84],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 10), 1.80],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 18), 1.80],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 24), 1.92],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 4), 2.49]

                    ]
                }, {
                    name: 'Winter 2008-2009',
                    data: [
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 18), 0],
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 26), 0.2],
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 1), 0.47],
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 11), 0.55],
                        [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.38],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 8), 1.38],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19), 1.6],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 25), 0.6],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 31), 0.35],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 7), 0]
                    ]
                }, {
                    name: 'Winter 2009-2010',
                    data: [
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 1, 23), 0.77],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 8), 0.77],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 14), 0.79],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 2, 24), 0.86],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 4), 0.8],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 18), 0.94],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 24), 0.9],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 16), 0.39],
                        [Date.UTC(1971, 4, 21), 0]
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });

</script>
```

This is the link to my fiddle:
and this is the link to my Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vbsvbs/LFXBd/ 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the outputted html and check whether the url to highcharts.js is correct.

If not you should adjust

```
src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/ext/highcharts.js"
```

accordingly. Your error message suggests that this is not the case.

Alternatively load from their cdn:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

/Casper